# command for adding a program at windows bootup

Tags: windows, command-line, boot, java

I want to add a java program in windows system boot up. Is there a command to do so??
I tried searching the internet and found steps to add a program but i need commands which i can implement in my code..
These are the steps that add a particular program to the startup:

```
1.Click "Start" and "open your personal folder".
2.Click on "App Data".
3.Click "Roaming".
4.Click "Microsoft".
5.Click "Windows".
6.Click "Start Menu".
7.Click "Programs".
8.Click "Startup".
9.Create a shortcut of the file. Paste it in the "Startup" folder.
10.Restart your computer. Now your program starts automatically.
```

or is there any way to convert these steps into a command. so that when I run my code the program should be added to the start up. Is there a way to achieve it?

Comment: Java is OS agnostic so it doesn't know how to create shortcuts natively. There are several ways to do that though: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19629034/create-shortcut-in-windows-programmatically Aside from that, it is just a matter of putting the shortcut in the correct location.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would skip the startup menu and use the registry instead. Your program can run the following command:

```
REG ADD "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run" /V "My App" /t REG_SZ /F /D "C:\MyAppPath\MyApp.exe"
```

for the whole system (all users) or

```
REG ADD "HKCU\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run" /V "My App" /t REG_SZ /F /D "C:\MyAppPath\MyApp.exe"
```

for just the current user.